# Which is the difference between "/usr/local/apache2/original" vs "/usr/local/apache2/extra" in httpd:2.4 apache image (docker)?

Tags: docker, apache, configuration

Recently my teacher has tried to teach us docker just about 3 days (because we are running out of time), however we are used to using Lamp only. Files structure of Lamp is different from apache image in docker, so I am a bit confused with a few things.

I do not know the difference between directories "extra" and "original".
Is "extra" the directory where I should write virtualhost files? Like -> "mysite.conf".
Are there any differences with .conf files in Lamp?

I ask because I have not seen the typical "directive" of "<Virtualhost *:80>" written in the default.conf file (httpd-default.conf).